# How to bypass web site redirect screen?

Tags: php, goutte

I try to download content of the web page with web scraping but on of the main problems is I can not bypass redirect of websites. for example when I try  login to the website and submit the login form. I see waiting page and just waiting  page.

but in browser  after waiting page I redirect to profile page

I downloaded `goutte` and created my script but in  submit form I have problem because when I submit wrongdoer password  or username I will see incorrect password but when I enter correct username and password I will see  waiting image to redirect

> First Edit

according to the update  response my code is

```
<?php

require_once  'vendor/autoload.php';


use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$url = 'https://egghead.io/users/sign_in';
$username = 'xxxx';
$password = 'xxxx';

$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'allow_redirects' => true
]);

$form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign In')->form();

$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('user[email]' => $username, 'user[password]' => $password));

$crawler->filter('body')->each(function ($node){
    print $node->html();
});
```

Comment: are you trying to scrap javascript site with PHP? *sigh* ... or I don't understand your question?

Comment: Your scraper needs to maintain the cookie login as well.

Comment: so you're trying to scrap http://example2.com but in order to do that you need to have a valid login from http://example1.com as well?

Comment: @Flash Thunder | yes I trying to web scraping a page but I am not  sure  the website use JavaScript   for redirect or not because when I disable JavaScript the  page redirect again

Comment: @Ahmed Saleh  |  example2.com is a website like egghead.io for sell course. I need to submit form to login  and then download course. the problem is  login page protected with waite screen

Answer (score 0):

Goutte will automatically follow redirects unless you tell it not to. You can customize the redirect behavior using the allow_redirects request option.

- Set to true to enable normal redirects with a maximum number of 5
  redirects. This is the default setting.
- Set to false to disable redirects.
- Pass an associative array containing the 'max' key to specify the
  maximum number of redirects and optionally provide a 'strict' key
  value to specify whether or not to use strict RFC compliant redirects
  (meaning redirect POST requests with POST requests vs. doing what
  most browsers do which is redirect POST requests with GET requests).

ref:
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#redirects

## Update:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://egghead.io', [
    'allow_redirects' => true
]);
$crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Sign in')->link());
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Sign in')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('login' => 'fabpot', 'password' => 'xxxxxx'));
$crawler->filter('.flash-error')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but No your answer dose not work